# Does autotools Makefile automatically consider included header files as dependencies?

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, automake

I have an autotools-managed project ([sscce](http://pastebin.com/p9d1XNcU) tar.gz package [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw9sT8pzNEH7Y3ZNM3FaWjlQaFk)) with this structure:

[`./main.c`](http://pastebin.com/dMPNukHi)
[`./foo.c`](http://pastebin.com/p9d1XNcU)
[`./foo/foo.h`](http://pastebin.com/xN0UQWeR)

My `configure.ac` is:

```
AC_INIT([foo], [1.0], [foo@bar.ba])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Wall -Werror])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])

AC_OUTPUT
```

My `Makefile.am` were:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.c foo.c foo.h
```

It compiled and ran perfectly... but then I note my `Makefile.am` was not correct. It stated that my main code depended upon `foo.h`, but the real file was `foo/foo.h`. I changed it, and the compilation was working as expected, as it was before:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.c foo.c foo/foo.h
```

However, it made me wonder: how did it work when the dependencies were wrong? It worked so well that I could even edit `foo/foo.h` and `make` would recompile the dependent files. Actually, I could even remove the header file from the dependencies...

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.c foo.c
```

...and it would be still scanned an would trigger the recompilation of dependent files.

So, my questions are:

- How does the autotools-generated `Makefile` know that `foo/foo.h` is a dependency to be analyzed during the `make` invocation?
- Should I add the header files to the `main_SOURCES` variable?
- Shouldn't `make` fail in the first case, since I am declaring that a non-existent file is a dependency?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you omitting some details?  How is `-I$(srcdir)/foo` getting into `CPPFLAGS`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Well, I am omitting some details of my *real* scenario, but the example below compiles as expected. In this case, there is no need for `-I$(srcdir)/foo` because both `foo.c` and `main.c` includes the file with the dir name: `#include "foo/foo.h"` as seen [here](http://pastebin.com/p9d1XNcU).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Dependencies). Dependency computation is done at build time, as a side-effect of compilation. The [history of dependency tracking](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/history/html_node/Dependency-Tracking-Evolution.html) might also be interesting to you. Note that there's an error in the manual here: it makes it sound like `depcomp` is unconditionally invoked, which is not the case (a test at `configure` time checks if your compiler can do without it: see the `@am__fastdepCC_TRUE@` lines in `Makefile.in`.

So what happens is that files listing the dependencies of each object are stored in a hidden subdirectory called `.deps`. These files are initally empty and get overwritten as their corresponding source file is compiled. (For `gcc`, this is done via `-MD` and related flags.)

You should absolutely list your headers in the `main_SOURCES` variable, so that your `Makefile` will package them up when you run `make dist` (or better yet, `make distcheck`).

`make` won't fail if you list a non-existent header, because you're not actually listing the dependencies in your `main_SOURCES` line. `automake` will process that assignment and then write out the rules for building `main` (which will depend on object files only) and the various object files (via a suffix rule). The headers aren't the **direct** input file to anything in the build process, so you skate by. Running `make dist` on your sample project gives the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `foo.h', needed by `distdir'.  Stop.
```